# Python find curve fit of slightly inclided vertical

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of data points on the two-axis scale. I want to fit the points. The number of datapoints runs into a few thousand. Here, I have given reproducible shape data points.

My code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x1 = [327.98999023, 327.98999023, 328.02999878, 367.6499939 ,
       374.72000122, 372.73001099, 372.95001221, 373.02999878,
       379.39001465, 375.58999634, 378.97000122, 378.1499939 ,
       380.70001221, 379.42999268, 379.5       , 379.5       ,
       392.22000122, 379.57998657, 376.67999268, 376.67999268]
ym1 = [2.54999995, 2.73999989, 2.91000009, 2.96999991, 3.17000002,
       3.40000004, 3.60000014, 3.77999991, 3.98999989, 4.21000004,
       4.44000006, 4.62000012, 4.83999997, 5.19999981, 5.32999992,
       5.59000015, 5.88999987, 6.20000005, 6.46000028, 6.66999996] 

def testfit(x, *p):
    ''' function to fit the indentation curve 
    p = [x0,c, poly1d_coeffs ]'''
    x = x.astype(float)
    y = p[1]*(1-sigmoid(x-p[0],k=1)) + np.poly1d(p[2:])(x) * sigmoid(x-p[0],k=1)
    return y

def sigmoid(x, k=1):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-k*x))

p0_guess = (30, 5, 0.3, -10 )
popt, pcov = curve_fit(testfit, x1, ym1, p0=p0_guess)    # find optimal parameters
# calculate prediction
yp1 = testfit(x1,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
# calculate r^2
r1 = r2_score(ym1,yp1)
print(r1)
plt.plot(x1,ym1,'.')
plt.plot(x1,yp1,'-')
plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
r1
Out[128]: -2.1490993028157854 # Negative fit score, Really bad fit.
```

[image]

Comment: do you get any warning?

Comment: @AminGheibi No warning. It executed perfectly.

Comment: cannot comment based on the plot, because the density of points is not clear. You might have too many points close to (300,0) that holds the line (on top of each other). The example in the question is also producing a warning about the covariance matrix.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: Do the data look like a sigmoid function to you? If so, I have to disagree. But yeah, what is the question here?

Comment: @mikuszefski   Might be I am using the wrong function here. Which function do you think best fits my data set.

Comment: @Mr.T Might be I am using the wrong function here. Which function do you think best fits my data set.

Comment: Hard to guess a function as (and @AminGheibi mentioned this above) the point density is not clear. Visually the big branch is dominant but the big dot at about (170,5) could be 500 points slightly smeared out. Can you provide information on where the data is from?

Comment: @mikuszefski I agree with you. There you may see around a few thousand points. I get from the field. Two sensors provide me data. They are plotted in the x and y-axis respectively.

Comment: Can you share your data? What are you measuring that makes you believe there is a relation that can be expressed as a function?

Comment: @mikuszefski That's an interesting approach. However, we do not have a direct equation to relate these two parameters.

Comment: You somewhat lost me: if there is no equation, what is the fitting about?

Comment: Looking at the data, the points left of x = 325 seem to be outlayers. You should then have a line approx. passing by (375, 100) and (370, 0). It is important to not blindly rely on a library function call and switch off your thinking.